# Creating a dictionary in python by condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to get a dictionary from an available numeric list, divided by digits and their number in a string.

My inputs:

```
num_list = list('181986336314')
```

I need to get a dictionary like this:

```
mydict = {1: 111, 2: None, 3: 333, 4: 4, 5: None, 6: 66, 7: None, 8: 88, 9: 9}
```

Comment: What Output do You need?

Comment: "I was getting an expression with a number" which expression your question is incomplete updated the question with proper details

Comment: This:
dict = {1: 111, 2: None, 3: 333, 4: 4, 5: None, 6: 66, 7: None, 8: 88, 9: 9}

Comment: don't use `dict` as a variable name

Comment: Counter counts the number of times the character appears.  In your example '1' appears 3 times not 111 times, and the key is '1' not 1 if course since you are working with a string and not an int.  However, you can now convert the keys and values to what you want.

Comment: Having the empty string rather than `None` for the missing digits would make more sense. That way the values would have a consistent type.

Comment: That's the point: 111 is three units

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to post engineer your counter result

```
counter = Counter(num_list)
my_dict = {}
for i in range(1, 10):
    if (str(i) in counter.keys()):
        my_dict[i] = int(str(i) * counter[str(i)])
    else:
        my_dict[i] = None
    
print(my_dict)
> {1: 111, 2: None, 3: 333, 4: 4, 5: None, 6: 66, 7: None, 8: 88, 9: 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could keep the digit string as a string and use a dictionary comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter
s = '181986336314'
c = Counter(s)
d = {digit:digit*c[digit] for digit in '0123456789'}
```

Resulting dictionary:

```
{'0': '', '1': '111', '2': '', '3': '333', '4': '4', '5': '', '6': '66', '7': '', '8': '88', '9': '9'}
```

In this approach I used `''` instead of `None` since that way the values have a consistent type. Furthermore, they all have the same meaning: a string of the given length consisting of the given digit.